# how to align two widgets vertically center and on bottom of first container flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

**place Icon on bottom center of container**

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          border: Border.all(width: 4, color:AppTheme.appColors )),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Text(

          text,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    ),

    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp,
          size: 25,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ),

  ],
);
```

I do not want to hard code height and width in stack view I referred other answers. Please suggest other ways
[image]

Comment: what two widgets do you mean? "Dealer" and "Charging point"?

Comment: no the marker bitmap descriptor 
EVMS/HSD M/s.
ELSHADDAI
ACENCIES and Icon below it

Comment: the icon is below the container but outside the border because you added the decoration to that container and not to the whole column

Comment: No I want remove the unnecessary space between icon and container

Comment: I updated my answer with an image can you please check

Comment: this is a space in the icon design, you can easily check that there is no space between widgets by adding `debugPaintSizeEnabled = true` in your code

Comment: And if you want to move it up use `Transform.translate` or `FractionalTranslation` for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256811/discussion-between-nandyala-raja-pragnesh-reddy-and-pskink).

Comment: super transform,translate is the solution for me thank you so much